# Tomcat heap space full

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

After few days of running my java app on tomcat I get 100% CPU load on tomcat process. I did `jmap` to detect full memory. The app still process all incomming TCP request but does not start Web page (beacuse of full memory)

Why is CPU to 100%? Because of running Java Garbage Collector? But why it takes several hours? I have had to kill the process manualy a start tomcat again.

How to better setup tomcat memory with parameters `Xms` or `Xmx`?

```
using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 2 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 0
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 100
   MaxHeapSize      = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 536870912 (512.0MB)
   G1HeapRegionSize = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 84410368 (80.5MB)
   used     = 84410368 (80.5MB)
   free     = 0 (0.0MB)
   100.0% used
From Space:
   capacity = 3670016 (3.5MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 3670016 (3.5MB)
   0.0% used
To Space:
   capacity = 3670016 (3.5MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 3670016 (3.5MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 715653120 (682.5MB)
   used     = 715497816 (682.3518905639648MB)
   free     = 155304 (0.14810943603515625MB)
   99.97829898373111% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 78643200 (75.0MB)
   used     = 78253152 (74.62802124023438MB)
   free     = 390048 (0.371978759765625MB)
   99.5040283203125% used

31605 interned Strings occupying 3556200 bytes.
```

Comment: a behaviour like this usually indicates a _memory leak_ . Have you tried looking into this with some tool?

Comment: @Leviand - any recomentation how to detect memory leak on running app on tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, when memory gets bursted in this way, this could probably be caused by a memory leak.

The only way to detect this is with dedicated tools.

I suggest you to use **JProfiler** , you can find a guide [here](https://www.ej-technologies.com/blog/2017/03/finding-a-memory-leak-with-jprofiler/) on how to find a memory leak.

Hope this helps :)